# How do I pass an argument to an ImageJ macro from within an ImageJ Java plugin?

Tags: java, plugins, macros, imagej

I am trying to pass an argument from an ImageJ plugin to an imageJ macro. Basically, I call the macro from within my ImageJ Java plugin to open a stack of images and would like to be able to pass an integer value to the plugin to be able to append it to the end of a file path.

Right now I am able to open a stack of images, perform whatever operations I need to do to the active image inside the plugin, and then close the image stack so I can open the next stack of images.

This is the basic format of what I am doing in the Java Plugin:

```
(general import stuff)

import ij.plugin.Macro_Runner;

Macro_Runner test_runner = new Macro_Runner();
test_runner.run("OpenFrameSequence.ijm");
// pixel analysis
test_runner.run("closeMacro.ijm");**
```

Here is the Macro OpenFrameSequence.ijm:

```
var x = 0;
x = getNumber("Bias Frame Sequence Length:", x); 
run("Image Sequence...", "open=[C:\\Documents and Settings\\Developer\\Desktop\\PLPT_IMAGEJ_PICS\\BiasFrameSequence\\1.jpg] number=x sort use");
```

Here is the Macro closeMacro.imj

```
close();
```

The fourth line in the plugin section above is what I am having trouble with, there is another function that I can call `runMacro();` which is defined here:

http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/developer/api/ij/plugin/Macro_Runner.html

So what I want to do is this:

```
int i = 1;

test_runner.runMacro("OpenFrameSequence.ijm", i);
```

And then, in the macro, take the value of i and use it as a variable. The runMacro() function doesn't seem to be working (i've also tried to send a String in place of the int i).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In the javadoc of [`Macro_Runner#runMacro(String macro, String arg)`](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/developer/api/ij/plugin/Macro_Runner.html#runMacro%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), it says:

> Runs the specified macro on the current thread. Macros can retrieve
>   the optional string argument by calling the getArgument() macro
>   function. Returns the string value returned by the macro, null if the
>   macro does not return a value, or "[aborted]" if the macro was aborted
>   due to an error.

so the following Javascript (and the equivalent Java) works as expected:

```javascript
importClass(Packages.ij.plugin.Macro_Runner);

var i = 42;
mr = new Macro_Runner();
mr.runMacro("print(getArgument());", i);
```

If you want to run a *macro file* instead of raw macro code, you should use [`Macro_Runner#runMacroFile`](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/developer/api/ij/plugin/Macro_Runner.html#runMacroFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
test_runner.runMacroFile("OpenFrameSequence.ijm", i);
```